# QTable allow column resizing, but no smaller than contents

Tags: qt, qt5, qtableview, qt5.4

I have a QTable and allow the user to resize columns. However, I want to enforce a minimum column size based on the columns contents. What is the easiest solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's any easy way to solve, but maybe you could do this:

```
MyClass::MyClass
{
    // ...

    QHeaderView* header = ui->TableWidget->horizontalHeader();

    connect( header, SIGNAL( sectionResized( /**/ ) ), this, SLOT( onSectionResized( /**/ ) ) );

    // ...
}

void MyClass::onSectionResized( int aColumn, int aOldsize, int aNewSize )
{
    // Resize as you wish.
    ui->TableWidget->setColumnWidth( qMax( YourMinimum, aNewSize ) );
}
```

Check [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#sectionResized) for the mentioned signals.

Comment: I was afraid that allowing arbitrary resize and then fixing it would be the way to go :/. Thanks for confirming this. I will test this next week and accept if I know that it works.